# Is there a way to get warnings in goland ide project in text file?

Tags: go, goland

I have a task to get the unused warning and errors in a project in a text file so is there a script that can be written to get the warnings in text file?

Comment: Can you share an example? There is no way to enable highlighting for plain text files, but you can change a file extension.

Comment: I mean like in the ide there is a problems tab that contains the warnings and errors is there any way to put that in a text file?

Comment: No except change extension e.g. to `filename.go` or somefile.someext`.

Comment: If you just want to get the contents of the problems tab into a file manually then the tab has an "export" button (xml or html) and, on windows anyway, you can copy with Ctrl-C and paste elsewhere (format is not great but it works).

Comment: yes, I did that ran an inspection and clicked on export to XML, Thank you was not able to respond earlier.